# How to arrange fields of a form rendered by ModelForm?

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a form that has 24 fields and is generated by a ModelForm class. 
Currenty it is rendered like this:

```
<form action="/search/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
   <ul class="list-unstyled">
       <li>{{form.as_p}}</li>
   </ul>
<input  class="btn btn-primary ersal" type="submit" name="submit"  value="search" />

 </form>
```

It becomes too long and not so apealing so I am wondering if there is a way to arrange the rendered fields into, say 4 columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Django, but with front-end stuff like CSS

You can do something like `<div class="first-column">{{ form.some_field }}</div>` to access a certain field from 24 that you have and style it accordingly

Comment: Right. Thanks for the tip Mihai